# Trigger an function only after user stopped typing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Working on Registration component. Array dependency making the other function in UseEffect trigger for each User Input.

getData is triggered when there is a change in name state.Based on the resposne, autopopulating the other two textfields with help of setState.

loadData() is fetching the backend data needed for other component functionality.

```
export default function Registration() {

  const [fatherName, setFatherName] = useState('');
  const [MotherName, setMotherName] = useState('');
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  

  useEffect(() => {
    loadData();

    const getData = setTimeout(() => {
      if (name !== '') {
        getBusinessData(name).then((data) => {
          if (data) {
            setFatherName(data.data.fatherDetails)
            setMotherName(data.data.motherDetails)
          } else {
            console.log("Data fetching is not success or data not available");
            setFatherName('')
            setMotherName('')
          }
        });
      } else {
        setFatherName('')
        setMotherName('')
      }

    }, 1000)
    return () => clearTimeout(getData)

  }, [name])

  
  const loadData = () => {
    getCompliance().then((data) => {
      if (data && data.success) {
        // do something
      } else {
        console.log("Data fetching is not success");
      }
    });
  };
  return (
      <Box component="form" sx={{'& .MuiTextField-root': { m: 1, width: '25ch' }}} noValidate autoComplete="off" >
        
          <TextField id="outlined-search" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} label="name" />
          <TextField id="outlined-search"
            value={fatherName}
            name="fatherName"
            label="fatherName"
          />
          <TextField id="outlined-search"
            value={MotherName}
            name="MotherName"
            label="MotherName"
          />
          
      </Box>
    )
}
```

Issue is loadData() is getting triggered for each change in name state.

Requirement - Need to trigger getData() after name state is assigned and also to trigger loadData() only once not for every changes in name state

Comment: It looks like that `useEffect` already has a "cooloff period" implemented with the use of `setTimeout`.  So that operation doesn't run unless the component goes 1000ms without re-rendering (so a second after the user stops typing).  But you're calling `loadData()` *before* that `setTimeout` operation.  Perhaps you meant to include that *within* the `setTimeout` operation, so it also doesn't execute unless the user hasn't typed (and the component hasn't re-rendered) for 1000ms?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you only want to call `loadData()` once when the component loads. To do this, you simply need another `useEffect()` hook with an empty dependency array, as shown below. You can move your `loadData()` function into this hook, and call it as shown:

```js
useEffect(() => {
   const loadData = () => {
     getCompliance().then((data) => {
       if (data && data.success) {
         // do something
       } else {
         console.log("Data fetching is not success");
       }
     });
   };
   loadData();
}, [])
```

Comment: Wow.This works. Missed thinking in this way. Thanks much !